# Azure function triggers on Cosmos change but doesn't run

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a setup of two azure functions:

1. Nodejs function triggering on CosmosDbCollection and lease with a lease prefix unique to this function. This one works well. I can see it triggering in the log stream, and I can see it running (I can see my own logs from the function, and I can also see it making output changes to the cosmos item
2. Java function (called parseProduct) that also has a Cosmos trigger, and another lease prefix. This one **triggers, but doesn't run**. The log stream looks like this (after an item in cosmos has been updated):

```
    2021-06-23T07:24:19Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.parseProduct' (Reason='New changes on collection products at .....)
    2021-06-23T07:24:19Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id:...
    2021-06-23T07:24:19Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:... on workerId:...
```

And then *nothing* happens. It doesn't run any code, it doesn't give any errors. Our function.json looks like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "../product-parser-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "ourPackageName.productparser.Function.run",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "cosmosDBTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "productDocuments",
    "maxItemsPerInvocation" : 1,
    "leaseCollectionName" : "leases",
    "databaseName" : "product-management",
    "leaseCollectionPrefix" : "parse-product",
    "connectionStringSetting" : "OUR_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists" : true,
    "collectionName" : "products"
  }, {
    "type" : "cosmosDB",
    "direction" : "out",
    "name" : "productDocumentOut",
    "databaseName" : "product-management",
    "connectionStringSetting" : "OUR_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "collectionName" : "products"
  } ]
}
```

The hosts.json file looks like this

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "functions": [
    "parseProduct"
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "cosmosDB": {
      "connectionMode": "Gateway",
      "protocol": "Https"
    }
  }
}
```

The function is running on consumption plan, Linux, and is deployed via ARM templates.

Answer (score 1):

We figured it out. The function was deployed from the ARM template with an error in the Linux FX version. We had

```
"linux_fx_version": "JAVA|11",
```

but it was supposed to be

```
"linuxFxVersion": "JAVA|11",
```

Would have been really nice with an error in the ARM template validation, or in the function, though. We found it just by accident.

This error made the function trigger but not actually run.